# how to repeat a symbol every x occurrences

Tags: java

I am currently doing a small exercise in java to train. The goal is to repeat the 0 every 8 occurrences. The problem is that I do not really see how to do it, however I am sure it is stupid.

```
public class Grid {

    public void paint() {

        StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();

        for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++){

            for(int columns = 0; columns < 20; columns++){

                if(row == 0 && columns == 0){
                    builder.append("0");
                }

                else {
                    builder.append("1");
                }
            }

            builder.append("\n");

        }

        System.out.println(builder);
    }

}
```

Currently, I have this as rendered :
[image: Render]

I would like something like this for the whole length of the grid with 0 instead of 1 in the right place :
[image: Need]

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: read up about the modulus operator -  %

Comment: So how should it look?

Comment: @Jason This https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1oXW.png the red circle represents the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, you just need a counter which help you to track where to print 0. See the below code, I added a track counter in your function. 
Que: Why I compare counterToPrint0 with 9?
Ans: Because each time you are printing 0 at 9th place.

```
public class Grid {

    public void paint() {
        int counterToPrint0 = 0;
        StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();

        for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++){

            for(int columns = 0; columns < 20; columns++){

                if(counterToPrint0 == 0){
                    builder.append("0");
                }
                else {
                    builder.append("1");
                }
                counterToPrint0++;
                if(counterToPrint0 == 9){
                    counterToPrint0 = 0;
                }
            }

            builder.append("\n");

        }

        System.out.println(builder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I also thought of something like that but I didn't know how to set it up thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to think about it. Think of the total elements as rows * columns. Then consider that once our element hits the last column, we should create a new line.

```java
         public void paint(int rows, int columns, int repeat) {
            StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();

            int elements = rows * columns;

            for (int element = 1; element <= elements; element++) {
                builder.append(element > 0 && element % repeat == 0 ? "0" : "1");

                if (element > 0 && element % columns == 0) {
                    builder.append("\n");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(builder);
        }
```

```
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
11111110111111101111
11101111111011111110
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.